# Allow Apostrophe In Preg Match Validation

Tags: php, regex, validation, preg-match

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I'm using the following preg match expression as part of my field validation.

```
(!preg_match('/^$|^[A-Za-z0-9 .,;-]{5,60}$/', $address4))
```

The problem I'm having is that I'm unable to get this to work when I include an apostrophe as part of the characters I want to allow.

I've read a number of tutorials and have tried the following without any success, so I'm clearly doing something wrong:

`(!preg_match('/^$|^[A-Za-z0-9 .,;-\']{5,60}$/', $address4)),` and

```
(!preg_match('/^$|^[A-Za-z0-9 .,;-\'\]{5,60}$/', $address4))
```

I just wondered whether someone could possibly look at this please and let me know where I've gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The minus character in the character class of your regex must always be at the end. Otherwise it will be taken for a character range. So try to switch the apostrophe and the minus:

```
preg_match('/^$|^[A-Za-z0-9 .,;\'-]{5,60}$/', $address4)
```

Comment: Hi @nwellnhof, thank you very much for taking the time to reply to my post and for the solution. I've tried the code you kindly sent, and unfortunately this doesn't work. Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: Try wrapping the whole pattern in quotation marks " (instead of single quotes '), and then you can use ' unescaped. Does that make any difference? It really _shouldn't_, but who knows. It works fine without the ' or \'? And of course, you're careful that this is a real ASCII single quote and not some MS Smart Quotes dross?